# How to get n documents after _id in sorted collection

Tags: mongodb, pagination, aggregation-framework

i want to use cursor based pagination on a mongodb collection with a sort.

Here's a sample collection

```
{
  _id: 3,
  name: 'aaa'
},
{
  _id: 2,
  name: 'bbb'
},
{
  _id: 1,
  name: 'ccc'
}
```

So in my first query, i will sort the collection by `name` ascending order and limit by 1 the first document will be

```
{
  _id: 3,
  name: 'aaa'
}
```

This is where i need help, i now need a query, that sorts the collection by `name` and returns `n` documents after the `_id:3` but in the sorted collection.

I need it to return

```
{
  _id: 2,
  name: 'bbb'
}
```

Essentially it needs to look through the sorted list, find the _id i'm providing, and return `n`documents after that one.

I'm operating inside an aggregation pipeline, and i know i could possibly use $group and create a single document with an array of all the sub documents, then use $filter. but that seems really inelegant, and i'm worried about performance.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps this is the feature that would solve the issue? https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8065

Comment: I'm confused, If you find X, you want n documents after X, sorted by `name` or sorted by `_id`? If sorted by name, how is it different from skip: 1, limit: n ?

Comment: Or is X not always the first document in the sorted result?

Comment: Well, yes and no. If we were using page based pagination, the input for our pipeline would be limit and skip, then we could do it this way. But we are using cursor based pagination, so the only input we have is the _id of the last document in the previous pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `limit`, use the `batchsize` option with [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/index.html#find) to get the first document.  The command response will also include a cursor ID.

Then use that cursor ID with [getMore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getMore/index.html#getmore), and set the batchsize to the number of documents you want in that batch.